# How can i code for legend on matlab?

Tags: matlab

My plot have problem in legend, legend should be seen like: -------- 2sin(0.5x) and + cos(2x). But i can not make it.
please appreciate i am to stackoverflow and matlab too.

Here is my code:

```
% Create the x-axis
x = 0:pi/30:2*pi;

% Make a vector for 2sin(x/2)
y1 = 2*sin(x/2) ;

% Plot 2sin(x/2) as a solid line in red
plot(y1,'color','r')

% Make a vector for cos(2x)
y2 = cos(2*x);

% Use hold on to add a second plot to the graph
hold on

% Plot cos(2x)
plot(y1,'-r')
plot(y2,'+k')

% Activate a grid
grid on

% Create a legend
legend({'2sin(0.5x)','cos(2x)'})

% Add x and y labels
xlabel('x')
ylabel('2sin(0.5x) , cos(2x)')

% Add a title
title('This is my second MSUM plot')
```

[image: here is my plot]

Comment: You are plotting the sine wave twice.  Take out the line `plot(y1,'-r')` as it is redundant with the earlier `plot(y1,'color','r')`

Comment: Thank you. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Create the x-axis
x = 0:pi/30:2*pi;

% Make a vector for 2sin(x/2)
y1 = 2*sin(x/2) ;

% Plot 2sin(x/2) as a solid line in red

% Make a vector for cos(2x)
y2 = cos(2*x);

% Use hold on to add a second plot to the graph
hold on

% Plot cos(2x)
plot(y1,'-r')
plot(y2,'+k')

% Activate a grid
grid on

% Create a legend
legend({'2sin(0.5x)','cos(2x)'})

% Add x and y labels
xlabel('x')
ylabel('2sin(0.5x) , cos(2x)')

% Add a title
title('This is my second MSUM plot')
```